# Access to a value in SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Sorry to bother you for that but I'm stuck with this for a while.. Usually it's not a problem but this time I really can't figure it out..

I want to access to that value :

[image]

I tried several things, but every time I get a null value x) ..

I'm sure it's simple as hell but I haven't pratice my PHP skills for a while and maybe I need a coffee

Thansk for your help !

Comment: [Basic SimpleXML usage](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [`attributes()`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) to get the attributes of your SimpleXMLObject.

For example:

```
$attr = $yourXmlObject->attributes();
echo $attr['image'];
```

Comment: Thanks It works ;)
I tried this in one line and it didn't work ..